# Unable to publish to subscriber running on android

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosandroid, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to debug a pub-sub node pair implemented on android (ROS-android). Following are the details:

ROS-Core is running locally on android. A publisher and a subscriber are also running on the android phone (no emulator).

On PC side the following settings are made
ROS_IP=pc_ip, ROS_HOSTNAME=android_ip, ROS_MASTER_URI =android_ip

All nodes are visible when I run `rostopic list`
Able to echo the published topic. (std_msgs.String)
Not able to send data to the subscriber. Then I looked into the TCP packets (using wireshark) and it appears the following transactions are happening:

1. get pid  (method call)    - result : success
2. register service              - result : success
3. Some broken message passing  [FIN,ACK] [ACK]
4. register publisher           - result : success       RETURNS the right address of the subscriber

The ROS-master running on android is sending the correct address yet the android application is **crashing with following message**:

```
04-17 00:49:10.604 2563-3001/com.example.vivek.sampleb I/HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
04-17 00:49:10.605 2563-3001/com.example.vivek.sampleb I/HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request
04-17 00:49:10.608 2563-3001/com.example.vivek.sampleb I/HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
04-17 00:49:10.609 2563-3001/com.example.vivek.sampleb I/HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request
04-17 00:49:10.613 2563-3001/com.example.vivek.sampleb I/HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
    Retrying request
```

[image: Wireshark packets]

I hope someone here can help me with this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288824/unable-to-publish-to-subscriber-running-on-android/) by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> On PC side the following settings are made [..], `ROS_HOSTNAME=android_ip` [..]

this makes no sense to me. Why did you set `ROS_HOSTNAME` to the IP of the android device?

---

Edit:

> The ROS master is running on the android phone thus I set HOSTNAME to `android_ip`. Is that wrong?

yes, that is not correct. `ROS_IP ~= ROS_HOSTNAME`: both store information about the local machine, not something remote. Only `ROS_MASTER_URI` ever points to a remote IP / host.

Please note that only one of them is needed. If you set `ROS_IP`, you don't need `ROS_HOSTNAME` and the other way around.

Or to be more precise: don't fill in the same information in the two. `ROS_HOSTNAME` should be set to hostnames, and things will only work if you've got a working DNS for all involved hosts (note: both forward and reverse lookups need to work).

If you set `ROS_IP`, set it to an IP, not a hostname. If you do this, you don't need DNS, but it's obviously less flexible in the face of (frequent) IP changes of the involved hosts (such as with an 'overactive' DHCP server).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on 2018-04-17**:
The ROS master is running on the android phone thus I set HOSTNAME to `android_ip`. Is that wrong?  Moreover, As I was able to receive (`rostopic echo`) the data coming from the android phone I thought these settings are correct.

**Comment by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on 2018-04-18**:
Understood (Thank you). It works with the HOSTNAME set to PC's IP address. I am however getting another  ()[error while closing the connection to master](https://answers.ros.org/question/289042/ros-master-on-android-is-throwing-error-while-closing-connection/) . Would you please take a look